# Accepting a job offer without paper documentation? (with final update)

Tags: interviewing, job-search

FYI: The person to whom I refer is a recent college graduate.

Someone who is close to me is currently pursuing an Administrative Assistant position at an unnamed company. She had a first interview with one of the "office manager[s]" of this company less than a week ago and was asked if she would be willing to "come on board." The manager then proceeded to give her some basic, vague details on pay and benefits, *none of which was in writing*. The pay was determined by the manager asking her "what's your bottom dollar;" she bypassed that question and did not give a specific figure. It is not clear to her whether or not this situation meant that she had an offer.

She has requested documentation containing details on benefits from the manager and the manager, again, has not offered any *documentation* outlining benefits or pay, not even an offer letter or a contract.

Should this be a cause for concern? What would you suggest that she do? She has had interviews at other places and the manager seems, to her, rather desperate to hire her.

**Update**: Apparently it *was* an offer. The manager has now asked her to do a drug test, and she will start training next week. If anyone has any further commentary on this, please feel free to comment.

Comment: If it's not in writing, it's not an offer.

Comment: Sure, but, if you were her, how would you have responded to the question "are you willing to come on board"? As indicated above, the manager has failed to provide documentation.

Comment: I'd insist on getting a written offer, or if I was _desperate_ to take this job, I would send a written response to the manager (i.e. an e-mail) saying "I accept the offer that you made to me for the position of Administrative Assistant at a rate of $x/hour, and look forward to commencing my employment on <date>.  Please confirm if this suits.".  Then at least there's _some_ documentation of what was discussed, especially if you get a confirmation by e-mail.

Comment: Thank you @aroth. Is it reasonable to assume that the position is not legitimate if a written offer is not provided?

Comment: Depends.  The _position_ is probably legitimate, but the offer may not be.  Or the company may just be disorganized, particularly if it's a small startup.  Though when you say "unnamed company" do you mean that you're not naming the company to protect you friend's privacy, or that the company literally refuses to list/give its name?  If it's the second case, then probably the _entire company_ is not legitimate.

Comment: I'm not naming the company to protect my friend's privacy. Without releasing too many details, it is a well-known national chain.

Comment: Any reason why she can't show up on the first day of work and take care of all of this? It sounds like they'd be willing to have her come in tomorrow.

Comment: @aroth: Is a written offer letter anymore legally binding than a verbal one? What of the company goes bankrupt?

Comment: @JimG - Technically speaking in most locales verbal and written agreements are legally equivalent, yes.  But if a dispute arises, a written agreement is much easier to prove than a verbal one.  With a verbal agreement all the other person has to say is "I never said that", and you're basically out of luck.  Neither helps in the case of bankruptcy, but that's really a separate issue.

Comment: @aroth: So what's the legal remedy if the hiring company backs out of its "promise" for employment? One year's salary + benefits?

Comment: @JimG. - Depends upon locale.  But usually it would be one notice-period's worth of salary + benefits.  Though I think the OP is more concerned about the company not paying the rate that it promised, as opposed to the company not providing the job at all.  And if you can _prove_ that you were promised one rate and that you only received a lesser rate, the legal remedy is that you get paid the difference.  If you have no proof of the higher rate because it was only stated verbally, then all you're going to be legally entitled to is the minimum wage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Should this be a cause for concern?

The first impression is one of an unorganized manager (or even company), maybe worse.

> What would you suggest that she do?

She should write an e-mail or a letter to this company in which she

- thanks them for the interview and for their interest in hiring her.
- asks them for a written offer and contract
- states that she has other opportunities, so she would be glad to get their offer within one week (or so)

Then she should wait what happens. If an offer comes within the week, she should examine that offer. If no offer comes within the week, she should forget about this company.

Comment: Agreed 100%. The answer to "are you willing to come on board?" is "sure, send over a letter of offer".

Answer (score 5):

> What would you suggest that she do?

It's not at all uncommon for a verbal offer to be given. If a verbal acceptance is returned, then the written offer should follow. Some companies don't want to spend time writing up the formal details of an offer, until they first get a verbal acceptance.

She should talk with the manager who made the verbal offer, indicate if she tentatively accepts the offer or not, then ask for the written details.

Assuming it's true, she should say "I really like what I'm seeing and would love to work here! If you can send me a written offer with the details, I'll review it quickly and get right back to you."

Once she receives the written details, she can accept, reject, or negotiate changes in the offer as warranted.

Comment: +1 - Some companies don't have a "new hire packet" nor do they over-night hiring contracts. You show up the first day of work and take care of all that.

Answer (score 3):

I once got a verbal offer in an interview. I was told they couldn't wait to have me on board and to wait for my offer letter. Over a week later I received a rejection email.

Nothing is a sure thing until it's in writing.

In your friend's case, I feel she should keep interviewing. If all of a sudden she does get the paperwork/offer letter for this job, then all is right in the world. She should not start working there without an official offer letter though.

If I was in your friend's shoes, I'd contact the manager and the hiring manager and say that I'm still waiting on the offer letter and benefits documentation and ask if there is anything that is holding up the process. Sometimes hiring communities are in the way, or maybe getting the budget for a new person hasn't been approved yet.

That being said though, what does her gut say? If she's already feeling sketchy about this place, is it really some place she wants to work?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you already know the answer, but let me write it for you. Your friend does not have a real job unless she has it in writing. In the best case scenario, she may have a position with a company so immature it doesn't know the rudiments of human resources. In the worst case scenario, your friend may end up "donating" a week or more of her time working for a position that doesn't exist for an employer who has no legal obligation to pay her.

Comment: You might want to add.  The friend does not have a job until they are actually on the pay roll of the company.  Until that happens, even with a signed written offer, the job technically disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Being asked if you are willing to come on board is in no way a job offer. It is seeing if you are still interested in the job. It indicates you are **one of the people** they are interested in, but it does not commit them to choose you. Job offers come in writing with actual salary numbers attached.